# Is there a way to recognize context menu opened/closed in listview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using context actions (ViewCell.ContextActions) in a listview in a xamarin forms project. Since I have a "add new" button floating on top of the list, I would like to recognize when the context menu is opened or closed (so I can remove the button from the screen when the context menu is opened).
My question: Is there any way in xamarin forms to recognize when the context menu is opened?
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You could detect opened/closed status of the context menu in custom renderer .

#### iOS Example

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace FormsApp.iOS
{
    class MyRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe              
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Source = new NativeiOSListViewSource(e.NewElement as ListView);
            }
        }
    }

   

    public class NativeiOSListViewSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        IList<string> tableItems;
        ListView listView;
        public NativeiOSListViewSource(ListView view)
        {
            listView = view;
            tableItems = view.ItemsSource as IList<string>;
        }

        public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            base.CommitEditingStyle(tableView, editingStyle, indexPath);
        }

        public override void WillBeginEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            (App.Current as App).MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Open", "OK");
        }

        public override void DidEndEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            (App.Current as App).MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Close", "OK");
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("UITableViewCell") as UITableViewCell;
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "UITableViewCell");
            }
            cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row] as string; 

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return tableItems.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

You could create a custom listview in forms and  set a global variable(isOpen) to store the status .  The context menu  open in `WillBeginEditing` method and close in `DidEndEditing` method .

[image]